# Wix - Searching a pattern for condition

Tags: wix

anyone know how to search a pattern of wix condition?

example:

```
<Property Id="P_WORD12INSTALLED_32">
      <RegistrySearch Id="SearchWord12_32" Type="raw"
                Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\InstallRoot" Name="Path" Win64="yes" />
    </Property>
```

The result is c:\program files\Office\ etc.

So in my condition,

```
<?if P_WORD12INSTALLED_32 >< "Office" ?>
.. set a variable value or do somethg
<?endif?>
```

But above hitting error:
An illegal number was found in the expression 'P_WORD12INSTALLED_32 >< "Office"

Comment: This won't work: the preprocessor is executed at build time, while the property P_WORD12INSTALLED_32 is to be populated at install time...

Comment: It would be better if you describe what you're going to achieve, and people will be able to suggest how to do it with WiX